# Combine and Minify wp-admin files, also re-write URI's for CDN

Tags: admin, wp-admin, cdn

I'm currently using [WP-MINIFY](http://www.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-minify) to combine and minify my front-end files as I have a large number of plugins, it has helped greatly and I'm looking for a similar solution to help with backend performance issues.

Ideally a solution that would combine all backend admin files that are being loaded, especially those that are introduced by plugins.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: The core already minifies and concatenates admin files, if your asking how to do it for plugins as well you need to show us an example or be more clear since plugin recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I'm looking to combine/minify the plugin files that are loaded when you are logged into /wp-admin area. An example of what my /wp-admin/ source code looks like:
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://www.livefreedietravelling.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='farbtastic-css'  href='http://www.livefreedietravelling.com/wp-admin/css/farbtastic.css?ver=1.3u1' type='text/css' media='all' />` - this i do not need to be loaded, or at least combined with other plugin files loaded. Thanks